# vba copy range to cell in new worksheet

Tags: vba, excel

I have two sheets I am working with, within the same workbook. For each one I defined the variables `db` and `rs`.
The goal here is to copy a certain row (given it matches my conditions) from `db` to the **next empty row** on `rs`.

I've tried:
`db.Range(db.Cells(i, 1), db.Cells(i, M)).Copy _
     Destination:=rs.Cells(N, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)`
and
`Set resrow = db.Range(db.Cells(i, 1), db.Cells(i, M))
 'next line is completely wrong inside the Range bracket
   rs.Range(rs.Cells(N, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)).Resize(1, M).Value = resrow.Value`

Note that `i` and `M` are `integers`.
I appears to me that I am trying to set a range value to a cell. How can I best fix it?

Thanks in advance

Comment: `Range.Copy` will automatically size the `Destination` range to fit.

Comment: Both samples look correct.  What is the problem?

Comment: It would be better to show the complete subroutine.

Comment: thx for replying. i guess the problem is I'm calling `Cells` in destination...isn't it, TinMan? What would your line look like?

Comment: the sub is quite large, given that there's a bunch of ifs and fors

Comment: `rs.Cells(N, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)` is a range that refers to the first empty cell in the first column on the worksheet `rs`.  The code above will expand that range to fit `db.Range(db.Cells(i, 1), db.Cells(i, M))`.  Unless your `Cells` parameters are incorrect, the code should function properly.

Comment: I guess for next empty row, the destination should be `Destination:=rs.Cells(rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Avoid Copy & Paste to reduce memory usage and improve the VBA performance

```
Set rng1 = db.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp)
Set rn2 = db.UsedRange
col = rn2.Columns.Count

For Each cel In db.Range("A2:A" & rng1.Row)
   if (condition) then
      Set rng2 = rs.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp)
      rs.Range(Cells(rng2.row, 1), Cells(rng2.row, col)).Value = db.Range(cells(cel.row,1),Cells(cel.row,col)).Value
   end if
Next
```

Comment: really helped a lot! I had to make some adjustments to my specific case, but you nailed it!

Answer (score 0):

I think you are mixing ranges with cells, I'd try something like:

```
rsLastRow = rs.UsedRange.Rows.Count

db.Range(Cells(i, 1), Cells(i, M)).Copy
rs.Range("A" & rsLastRow).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
```